# Allowing deep imports from npm packages without a build directory (like lib/dist) in the path

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg, packaging

The standard approach when packaging code for npm is to place transpiled or bundled code in a separate `lib`, `dist` or `build` directory and to set the `package.main` property (and `module`/`browser`) to point to the built files, which makes the existence of the build directory transparent when doing bare imports (without a path). However, if deep imports are needed (importing specific modules not referenced in `package.json` properties), it means that the build directory needs to be included in the path like so: `require('package/lib/some-module')`, which looks bad.

Are there any examples of an approach that would at the same time:

1. Support deep imports without the build directory in the path
2. Support `npm-link` and tools like Lerna
3. Still place the built files in a separate directory for tidiness

Every approach I've tried or seen fails to fit one of the criteria; for example, copying `package.json` into the build directory (`lib`/`dist`) allows publishing or linking the package from the build directory, but tools like Lerna don't support this approach since they expect the `package.json` to be in the root of the package instead of the build directory, so only points 1 and 3 are met.

Placing sources in the root of the package and the transpiled or built files next to the sources allows deep imports and is also supported by Lerna, but it doesn't meed the 3rd criteria (tidiness).

Having [import maps](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps) would solve this issue, but I'm not sure if any tool supports import maps yet.

The question is: is there some approach that I've missed that could meet all three listed points?

Comment: Related discussion about [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/1282); it seems that this may be just a limitation of Lerna.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. You mean something like that require('package').some-module ?? 

This is possible, by creating an index in the root of your code and export all the modules from that, so you don't have to use the absolute path.
If this is what you are looking for I have an example in github to link

Comment: Bare import: `require('package')`. Deep import: `require('package/directory/module')`. The question is about deep imports.